# Get text data from json

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

Here I have a code that must return me a reviews... so I have an array with `reviews[i]`

I try with `places.reviews[0].text` but I get only first reviews, I want to get it 5 if there is 5, if there is 3 I want to get 3 reviews...

But how I can increment i... how to write a code to get me all reviews from array `reviews[i]`?

I try:

```
    contentStr += '<br>'+place.reviews[0-4].text+'</p>';
```

but it doesn't work.

Also there is rating to get `place.reviews[0-4].rating` ...

Comment: Iterate over the reviews array and concatenate on a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var contentStr = "";    
for(var i=0;i<place.reviews.length;i++){
  contentStr += place.reviews[i].text;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to get each review then you need to loop through the array in your javascript.

using jQuery (which you have tagged) you can do

```
$("#MyArray").each(function(i){
    //logic to do what you want with the results here.
}
```

Comment: @MarcoJordan I've edited my answer to include a jQuery looping function.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is some kind of a loop that increments the index.
How about a for-loop?

```
var contentStr = '';
for(var i = 0; i < place.reviews.length; i++){
    contentStr += '<br>'+place.reviews[i].text;
}
```

And the same goes for ratings.